# Автоматическое присваивание вариативных обработчиков событий

Tags: javascript

допустим HTML есть 3 кнопки:

```
<input type = button value = 'раз' buttonOrder='0'></input>
<input type = button value = 'два' buttonOrder='1'></input>
<input type = button value = 'три' buttonOrder='2'></input>
```

Есть массив `obj`

```
obj = ['lorem','ipsum','dolor'];
```

Есть функция `func`

```
function func(order)  {
alert(obj[order]);
}
```

Требуется *автоматически* повесить на кнопки обработчик событий т.е. `func()`, так чтобы ей передавался аттрибут `buttonOrder` и, в конечном итоге, при нажатии на первую кнопку выскакивало "lorem", на вторую - "ipsum", на третью - "dolor".

Я пробовал применить и .onclick свойство объекта и .addEventListener но как я ни пытался, вставить функцию вместе с аргументом не удалось.

Как мне автоматизировать присвоение функций с различными аргументами?

Comment: onclick='func(...)'  так пробовали и не работает?

Comment: Это либо вручную прописывать в HTML, что мне не нужно, либо через .onclick аттрибут, но тогда не получается вписать в `func()` аргументы.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если вы хотите присваивать атрибут `buttonOrder` динамически - дайте знать в комментарии.

**ES15**

```js
let obj = ['lorem','ipsum','dolor'];

document.querySelectorAll("input[type='button']").forEach((item, index) => {
  item.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    let elem = e.currentTarget;
    let buttonOrder = elem.getAttribute("buttonOrder");
    alert(`buttonOrder: ${buttonOrder}\nobj: ${obj[buttonOrder]}`);
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="button" value='раз' buttonOrder="0"></input>
<input type="button" value='два' buttonOrder="1"></input>
<input type="button" value='три' buttonOrder="2"></input>
```

**По-старому**

```js
var obj = ['lorem','ipsum','dolor'];

document.querySelectorAll("input[type='button']").forEach(function (item, index) {
  item.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var elem = e.currentTarget;
    var buttonOrder = elem.getAttribute("buttonOrder");
    alert("buttonOrder: " + buttonOrder + "\nobj: " + obj[buttonOrder]);
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="button" value='раз' buttonOrder="0"></input>
<input type="button" value='два' buttonOrder="1"></input>
<input type="button" value='три' buttonOrder="2"></input>
```

Comment: Вы используете синтаксис такой как  `=>` и `$`. Это ведь не чистый джаваскрипт? Потому что я пишу на чистом.

Comment: Это чистый js, es15. Никакого jQuery

Comment: [Про =>](https://learn.javascript.ru/es-function), [про ${}](https://learn.javascript.ru/es-string)

Comment: @IgorCheglakov отредактировал ответ по старой спецификации

Comment: Я что-то пропустил, каким образом в Вашем примере аргумент `e` равняется объекту `event`?

Comment: @IgorCheglakov, объект event передается в качестве первого параметра в обработчик события